# Does vnd.safari://example.com work as uri scheme in ios

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, ios

I found this link from source sode of some website
`vnd.youtube://www.youtube.com`
It force url to open in YouTube app on ios Device
Can it also works on safari
`vnd.safari://www.google.com`
To open links in safari

**I don't have ios Device to test **
Can someone help me to test it

---

Place this code as

<a href="vnd.safari://Google.com"> in a working server an try to open link in chrome can it open safari